# Where do absent dots (`...`) get processed?

Tags: r, arguments

If we view the body of a function that has dots `...` in its argument list, we can usually find the function that receives those dots arguments.

For example, we can see in the body of `sapply()` that the dots arguments are passed through to `lapply()`.

```
sapply
# function (X, FUN, ..., simplify = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE) 
# {
#     FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
#     answer <- lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...)
#     ## rest of function body
# }
# <bytecode: 0x000000000e05f0b0>
# environment: namespace:base>
```

However, in `lapply()`, there are dots `...` in the argument list but **not** in the function body.

```
lapply
# function (X, FUN, ...) 
# {
#     FUN <- match.fun(FUN)
#     if (!is.vector(X) || is.object(X)) 
#         X <- as.list(X)
#     .Internal(lapply(X, FUN))
# }
# <bytecode: 0x0000000009414f08>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

So where do the dots `...` arguments in `lapply()` get processed?  What/where are they passed to? We cannot pass them to `match.fun()`.  I presume they are passed into `.Internal()` but I don't see any reason for this to work when I don't see them passed into any function in the function body.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're not explicitly *passed* to `.Internal`, but I believe they're available to `do_lapply` (in src/main/apply.c) via dynamic scope. The scoping rules may be slightly different than usual, since `.Internal` is a primitive function.

You can see that `...` (`R_DotsSymbol`) is added to the function call `lapply` creates, so they're available to the function call on each list element. `tmp` is roughly equivalent to `X[[i]]` and `R_fcall` is roughly equivalent to `FUN(X[[i]], ...)`.

```
SEXP tmp = PROTECT(LCONS(R_Bracket2Symbol,
        LCONS(X, LCONS(isym, R_NilValue))));
SEXP R_fcall = PROTECT(LCONS(FUN,
             LCONS(tmp, LCONS(R_DotsSymbol, R_NilValue))));
```

Comment: I am guessing that the environment, `rho`, in the  `R_forceAndCall` is also important.

Answer (score 0):

> However, in `lapply()`, there are dots `...` in the argument list but not in the function body.

But they are in the environment in the body of the `lapply`! The lines of interest are:

- the [`do_apply` C function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2cdea4811caa2417e2cf32a0c7ad3be70325eec1/src/main/apply.c#L29-L34).
- this [`ICONS` call](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2cdea4811caa2417e2cf32a0c7ad3be70325eec1/src/main/apply.c#L65).
- this [`R_forceAndCall`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2cdea4811caa2417e2cf32a0c7ad3be70325eec1/src/main/apply.c#L70).

We can do something very similar with the C++ file below which we can `Rcpp::sourceCpp` where we use [`Rf_lang3`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/54fbdca9d3fc63437d9e697f442d32732fb4f443/src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h#L719-L725) instead of the calling `ICONS`:

```cpp
 #include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
SEXP to_simple_call_f_1(SEXP f, SEXP x, SEXP env){
  SEXP fn  = PROTECT(Rf_lang3(f, x, R_DotsSymbol)), 
       ans = Rf_eval(fn, env);
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return ans;
}

// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
SEXP to_simple_call_f_2(SEXP f, SEXP x, SEXP rho){
  SEXP fn  = PROTECT(Rf_lang3(f, x, R_DotsSymbol)), 
       ans = R_forceAndCall(fn, 1, rho);
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return ans;
}

// [[Rcpp::export(rng = false)]]
SEXP to_simple_call_f_3(SEXP f, SEXP x, SEXP rho){
  SEXP fn  = PROTECT(Rf_lang2(f, x)), 
       ans = Rf_eval(fn, rho);
  UNPROTECT(1);
  return ans;
}
```

We can now see that:

```r
f <- function(x, ...)
  x * unlist(list(...))
w_wont_work <- function(x, ...)
  to_simple_call_f_1(f = f, x = x, .GlobalEnv)

# first the solution that does not work (wrong env!)
a <- 3
b <- 2
w_wont_work(x, a, b)
#R> Error in to_simple_call_f_1(f = f, x = x, .GlobalEnv) : 
#R>   '...' used in an incorrect context

# now with the correct versions
w_1 <- function(x, ...)
  to_simple_call_f_1(f = f, x = x, environment())
w_2 <- function(x, ...)
  to_simple_call_f_2(f = f, x = x, environment())
# version that uses variables from the global environment instead
f3 <- function(x)
  x * unlist(list(a, b))
w_3 <- function(x)
  to_simple_call_f_3(f = f3, x = x, environment())

# check the functions
f  (2, a, b)
#R> [1] 6 4
w_1(2, a, b)
#R> [1] 6 4
w_2(2, a, b)
#R> [1] 6 4
w_3(2)
#R> [1] 6 4

# almost runs in the same time
bench::mark(f(2, a, b), w_1(2, a, b), w_2(2, a, b), w_3(2), min_time = 1, 
            max_iterations = 1e9)
#R> # A tibble: 4 x 13
#R>   expression        min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`  n_itr  n_gc total_time 
#R>   <bch:expr>   <bch:tm> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>  <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> 
#R> 1 f(2, a, b)      995ns  1.15µs   801375.        0B     25.1 733096    23      915ms 
#R> 2 w_1(2, a, b)   1.96µs  2.25µs   420623.    6.77KB     26.0 388953    24      925ms 
#R> 3 w_2(2, a, b)   1.93µs  2.21µs   424811.    6.77KB     25.9 393580    24      926ms 
#R> 4 w_3(2)         1.76µs  1.99µs   474501.   15.23KB     22.5 442139    21      932ms
```

> I presume they are passed into `.Internal()` but I don't see any reason for this to work when I don't see them passed into any function in the function body.

Notice that the functions from Rcpp use `.Call` and not `.Internal`:

```r
to_simple_call_f_1
#R> function (f, x, env) 
#R> .Call(<pointer: 0x7fedc44cd1b0>, f, x, env)
```

Thus, I pass the environment. So it seems that `.Internal` passes an environment I guess? `?.Internal` is not that helpful.